# Javascript regex to match between two patterns, where first pattern is optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried so many things and tried adapting similar answers... but still lost today to this, if anyone can help I'd be eternally grateful!

I need to use a regex (the JS lexer-library I'm using doesn't allow for anything else) to match:

- Any content between `$$` and `*/`
- Must not include the opening `$$`
- But must include the closing `*/`
- The "content" can be any character/digit/whitespace/newline

Given this:

```
xxx. 123 $$yyy.234 */zzz.567
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

...I need the indicated string to be matched.

As such, this seems to work fine:

```
(?<=\$\$)(?:[\s\S])*?(?:[\s\S])*?\*\/
```

(...[as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/I4cRn3/3/))

But there's an additional requirement of:

- If there's no `$$`, then just match to the beginning of the string.

E.g.:

```
xxx. 123 yyy.234 */zzz.567
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Yeah, at the limits of my regex knowledge and just can't land it! :-(

Might be worth mentioning the opening `$$` symbol isn't quite that solid, it's more like:

```
\$[\p{L}0-9_]*?\$
```

Comment: According to your description, the pattern can look like `/(?<=\$\$|^).*?\*\//s`

Comment: Re "*Might be worth mentioning*", There are indeed important differences between a pattern that only matches single character, a pattern that only matches fixed number of characters, and a pattern that matches a variable number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When matching against `www $$ xxx $$ yyy */ zzz`, I'm assuming the result should be `$$ yyy */` rather than `$$ xxx $$ yyy */`. The solution may be more complicated than it needs to be if this isn't a requirement.

---

```regex
(?: ^ | \$\$ )        # Starting at the start of the string or at "$$"
( (?: (?!\$\$). )*    # A sequence of characters (.) now of which starting with "$$"
  \*/                 # Followed by "*/"
)                     # End capture
```

Except not quite. That will fail for `$$$abc*/`. So we fix:

```regex
(?: ^ | \$\$(?!\$) )  # Starting at the start of the string or at "$$" (but not "$$$")
( (?: (?!\$\$). )*    # A sequence of characters (.) now of which starting with "$$"
  \*/                 # Followed by "*/"
)
```

We could also avoid lookaheads.

```regex
(?: ^ | \$\$ )
( (?: [^$]+ ( \$[^$]+ )* \$? )?
  \*/
)
```

---

Regarding the the updated question, the lookahead version can be modified to accommodate `\$[\p{L}0-9_]*\$`.

```regex
(?: ^
|   \$ [\p{L}0-9_]* \$ (?! [\p{L}0-9_]* \$ )
)
( (?: (?! \$ [\p{L}0-9_]* \$ ) . )*
  \*/
)
```

---

I've used line breaks and whitespace for readability. You will need to remove them (since JS's engine doesn't appear to have a flag to cause them to be ignored like some other engines do).

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hi @ikegami, thank you for this, apologies, did you see my earlier edit? 
The requirements around the $$ symbol are a bit more relaxed than originally stated... it can have letters, digits and the _ character  between the dollars. 

So all these are valid opening symbols: $$, $hello$, $hello123$, $hello_123$. Thank you for you help, sorry, I didn't appreciate that this would affect the solution as much as it has. Unfortunately, I still can't quite get it to work.

Comment: That works like a charm @ikegami, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered and accepted. But here's the **shortest** way of doing it.

```js
let str = "xxx. $$ 123 $$yyy.234 */zzz.567";
let regex = /\$?\w*\$?([\w \d.-]*\$?[\w \d.-]*\*\/)/gm;

console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comments, the above method fails for  `a $ b */` kind of strings. So, I came up with this. This isn't as good as @ikugami's, but this can definitely be another way.

```js
let str = "$$xxx. $$gjjd*/ fhjgd";
let regex = /(\$?\w*\$?)([\w \d.-]*\$?[\w \d.-]*\*\/)/gm;

result = regex.exec(str).slice(1);

if (result[0].startsWith('$')) {
  result = result[1]

} else {
  result = result[0] + result[1]
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doesn't match `a $ b */`, `a $$ b */` or `a $$ b $ c */` correctly.

Comment: Still fails for `a $ b */`, though the other two cases I previously mentioned were fixed.

Comment: It also fails for the example the OP specifically asked for help with (`xxx. 123 yyy.234 */zzz.567`)

Comment: Ok I'm working on `a $ b */`. But @ikegami the case, OP specifically asked for help works. Using [rubular](https://www.rubular.com) to test my regex.

Comment: I put your exact code into the Firefox console (wrapped in `(function(){ ... })()` so I could run multiple tests). Maybe you meant to print `[0]` instead of `[1]`? But if you do that, it breaks `a $$ b */` and `a $$ b $ c */`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @Ava, unfortunately I can't use JavaScript on this occasion, only regular expressions.